# Origin file://127.0.0.1 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: macos, apache

Im runnig an application on my localserver on a mac, this application need to connect to a server domain.com/service.php, but when I call the service(http://127.0.0.1/webpage.php) from my local page appear the following error in the console

Origin file://127.0.0.1 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

some ideas about it?, on a windows local server it work perfect

thak you

Answer (score 0):

In your `webpage.php` source code, you need to add this code at the very top:

```
<?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); ?>
```

This is [a workaround for CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/http_access_control) (cross-origin resource sharing).

Comment: Hi thank,but what about an html file, is there a tag to do this on my local mac  apache server